# Need class to expose a private static function via handle

Tags: function, matlab, oop, static, private

I need a particular class to expose a private static function. I do this via an anonymous function stored in a cell array. The contrived example below illustrates the issue:

```matlab
classdef ParamClass
    properties (Constant)
        param_spec = {
            {'param_1', @(x) isnumeric(x) && isscalar(x) && (x > 0)}, ...
            {'param_2', @(x) ParamClass.validate_param_2(x)} ...
            };
    end
    
    properties
        param_1;
        param_2;
    end
    
    methods (Static, Access = 'private')
        function ok = validate_param_2(x)
            ok = isnumeric(x) && isscalar(x) && (x  < 0);
        end 
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = ParamClass(p1, p2)
            opts = parse_my_args(p1, p2, ParamClass.param_spec{:});
            obj.param_1 = opts.param_1;
            obj.param_2 = opts.param_2;
        end
    end
end

function opts = parse_my_args(p1, p2, varargin)
    assert(varargin{1}{2}(p1));
    assert(varargin{2}{2}(p2));
    
    opts.param_1 = p1;
    opts.param_2 = p2;
end
```

The function `ParamClass.validate_param_2` is private static, but I want it to be called by an outside standalone function via the anonymous function wrapper. However I get the following error:

> Error using ParamClass.validate_param_2
>
> Cannot access method 'validate_param_2' in class 'ParamClass'.

After some thought, the error seems unnecessary. The class passes a function handle to the outside. The contents of the handle should be a matter only for the class to decide and should not be anyone's business. Should not all the required context for `validate_param_2` be part of the anonymous function? Of course I can remove the error by making `validate_param_2` public, but I would like to understand the rationale behind the error.

Any comments explaining why this kind of error is needed would be appreciated. Also any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a strange error, and I don't think it makes much sense. One explanation could be that while the property constraints are being evaluated, the class definition is not yet complete in memory, and  the function `ParamClass.validate_param_2()` is not yet available. But again, there is no reason for it to be this way, it might not have been a conscious choice (i.e. it's a bug).

As an alternative, you could instead use [a local function](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/functions-inside-class-definition-files.html) (i.e. a function defined after the `classdef` block, in the same file). Such a function is visible only from within the file, but you can return a handle to it, to make it useable from another file. This local function also has access to private members of the class. For all intents and purposes it is a private member, except it's only visible from within the file—class methods defined in the `@ParamClass` directory will not be able to see it.

```matlab
classdef ParamClass
    properties (Constant)
        param_spec = {
            {'param_1', @(x) isnumeric(x) && isscalar(x) && (x > 0)}, ...
            {'param_2', @validate_param_2} ...
            };
    end
    
    properties
        param_1;
        param_2;
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = ParamClass(p1, p2)
            opts = parse_my_args(p1, p2, ParamClass.param_spec{:});
            obj.param_1 = opts.param_1;
            obj.param_2 = opts.param_2;
        end
    end
end

function opts = parse_my_args(p1, p2, varargin)
    assert(varargin{1}{2}(p1));
    assert(varargin{2}{2}(p2));
    
    opts.param_1 = p1;
    opts.param_2 = p2;
end

function ok = validate_param_2(x)
    ok = isnumeric(x) && isscalar(x) && (x < 0);
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This more or less solves the problem. One additional issue, not directly related to the exact problem and which I did not notice yesterday, is that in my example code I have, for convenience, put the function parse_my_args" in the class file. However, despite being in the class file Matlab is not letting it access the class private static "validate_param_2" via the cell array, as is evident from the error.

Comment: OK, sorry to continue this further, but in in the modified code that you posted, you have replaced @(x) ParamClass.validate_param_2(x) with @validate_param_2.
The latter works, but the former does not with matlab giving the error (which occurs in the parse_my_args function) "Unrecognized function or variable 'validate_param_2".

Unfortunately, in the original code, I need the anonymous wrapper as there are other variables involved.

Comment: @skm Re your 2nd comment: use `@(x) validate_param_2(x)`. It is not technically a member of `ParamClass`, so `ParamClass.validate_param_2` is not valid. Re your first comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. "as is evident from the error." What error? How are you trying to access that class private static function, what is "via the cell array"?

Comment: Once I took validate_param_2 outside the class and made it into a local function, I access it via the cell array which now contains the anonymous function @(x) validate_param_2(x) (note: _without_ the class namespace - there was a typo in the second comment). But I get the error "Unrecognized function or variable 'validate_param_2".

Comment: Regarding my first comment, what I mean is that if "parse_my_args" is in the class file, and Matlab allows class file local functions to access private class members, then in theory, the initial problem in the original post should never have occurred.

Comment: BTW, I'm using Matlab 2020a. Not sure if things are different in later versions.

Comment: @skm Are you testing with the MRE you posted on this page, or with the original class? I just tried this, and it works correctly for me. If you're testing with your original class and not the code here, there might be something else not captured by the MRE. Or this was a bug that has since been fixed (I'm on R2023b).

Comment: @skm [Here's a relevant bug report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/details/2394175), it was fixed in R2021a and R2020b Update 5. I'm not sure if this is what you're experiencing, but it seems very close. Basically it says that `ParamClass.param_spec{1}` might return the wrong value. A workaround is to do `tmp = ParamClass.param_spec; tmp{1}`.

Comment: I'm testing with exactly the code posted on this thread. Are you using an anonymous wrapper @(x) validate_param_2(x)?

Comment: Just saw you last comment. Will check it out.

Comment: @skm Yes, I did. And then I also tried with your original code (the static function), and got no error. This is why I was looking through the fixed bugs between 2020a and 2023b.

Comment: I did what the bug report suggested and used an intermediate variable
pspec = ParamClass.param_spec;
in the ParamClass constructor. Along with this change, I also inspected all the values in the debugger - all the values are as they are supposed to be. But I get the same error: "Unrecognized function or variable 'validate_param_2'". I am sure that there is no inadvertent error/typo - it is just a single file with the class definition and two local functions. I could post the modified code - but then I would have to answer my own question.

Comment: I'll try finding a recent Matlab version and running on that. It may be some time but I'll report back here. Thank you indeed for your efforts.

Comment: @skm You have access to the latest version of MATLAB here: https://matlab.mathworks.com -- you don't even need a MATLAB license to try it out there, just an account.

Comment: Well, what do you know - both the code in the original post as well as the local function version work perfectly well on the mathworks site. So I have to conclude that this issue can be regarded as an undocumented bug in 2020a.